# Why does window.requestAnimationFrame run the step function only once?

Tags: javascript, html

When opening the following HTML file in a browser, the timestamp is only logged once, why isn't the `step` function called a bunch of times per second as I would except?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function step(timestamp) { console.log(timestamp) }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It only ever runs once. For it to repeat we must call `requestAnimationFrame` inside `step` for it to continue https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Before:

```js
function step(timestamp) {
  console.log(timestamp)
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
```

After:

```js
let i = 0;

function step(timestamp) {
  console.log(timestamp);
  i++;

  if (i < 10) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(step)
```